# Template Error in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my blog folder as shown here in screen shot has the accounts folder [image]

I then proceed to next page from home page to my signin page in accounts folder 
[image]

I get the Following Error 
[image]

**Can someone please Help me**

Here is the settings.py file

> """

```
Django settings for luckdrum project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'q^6oh!prd$jt*@sz@#&n(i5$etxv-13-pr+%x9_0y$#7$tnfq('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'luckdrum.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'luckdrum.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/blog/templates/',
               '/home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/blog/accounts/',




)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
TEMPLATE_DEBUG =True
```

ERROR CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/signin.html/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/blog/views.py", line 27, in login
    return render_to_response('accounts/signin.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 39, in render_to_response
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 43, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/signin.html
[13/Dec/2015 07:06:07] "GET /accounts/signin.html/ HTTP/1.1" 500 75747
```

Comment: Add the error text and your settings.py

Comment: I don't see the error there. You've posted a part of stack trace. Please post text instead of images.

Comment: your html files should be in a flder named templates. Accounts wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the template files from the accounts folder to the template folder and the static files to the appropriate static folder. Django only looks for templates files in the folder named templates.

Also change the original `render_to_response` to `render_to_response('signin.html')`

Comment: I had added the following lines in settings.py shouldn't that work too? TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
               '/home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/blog/accounts/',)

Comment: change the original `render_to_response` to `render_to_response('signin.html')`

Comment: As i had added the template_dirs and added the render_to_response('signin.html') it is still showing the same error TEmplate not found. Am i proceeding right?

Comment: The error page must be showing you a list of directories it tried? Can you share the list?

Comment: It's giving me the same old error as i Template does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97749/discussion-between-black-user-and-utkbansal).